# How to undo incorrect manual recursive changes in file and directory permissions?

Tags: unix, perforce, file-permissions

I am new to perforce and unix. While doing a **'p4 sync'** was getting an error **"can't clobber writable files"** for some of my files.
I then did a **"chmod -R 555 ./*"** , thinking that it would remove the write permissions for the files that were giving me the above mentioned error. I didn't know that we have different permissions for directories and files in perforce. So now I have set r-x permissions for all directories and files, and now when I try to do a 'p4 sync' I am getting the following kind of error for all the files:

**open for write: /home/path_to_file/tmp.18455.196170: Permission denied**

What should I do to revert back the original permissions that perforce provides?

Comment: If you can, become root and reset the permissions.

Comment: @cad: I suppose the "..but how?" is the point of this question

Comment: Harley - I edited the title to make it a bit more focused on what you are actually asking for at the end of the text. If that's not the point, please re-edit and put a better title

Comment: I can change the permissions of the files and folders in my perforce client. But I have set the permission of every file and directory to 555. Perforce by itself sets different permissions for directories and files ( for directories it is read-and-execute and for files it is read only.) How do I get back these permissions?? I obviously cannot do that individually for each file and directory.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to apply different permissions to files vs directories is to use find, like so:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 444
```

This would apply permissions `755`to directories and `444`to files.

However, please note I don't know which permissions you have to apply in your case, you may want to look at another installation to get an idea. In your case I suspect the error message comes from the directories missing write permissions.

Also note that using an octal mask with chmod is not necessarily what you want, as it means "assign these permissions"; when you want to "remove" or "add", it's usually better to use a symbolic mode; for example, to remove all three write bits on files only, you would specify `a-w`(remove `w` to `a`ll fields):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-w
```

Finally, note that you can use find to recursively list permissions of all files and directories, for manual verification:

```
find . -ls
```

Comment: Well, I am looking for a more perforce specific solution. Is there a way by some perforce command that would force a sync, and also reset the permissions of files and directories correctly.

Comment: @Harley rm -r your-perforce-client-root-directory; p4 sync -f

Comment: Yes....that is ultimately what I did. I just wanted something more authentic. Because this "can't clobber writable files" error is something which I start to get every now and then. Thanks bdw. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that files in the workspace are writable, but have not been checked out by 'Perforce' (opened for edit).

If you want writable files to be overwritten by files you sync from Perforce, set the 'noclobber' option to 'clobber' in the  client spec.

More information about this option and the 'p4 client' command is available here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html#p4_client.usage

Hope this helps,
Jen.